# Zend Framework 2 form annotation is ignored without an extra space

Tags: php, forms, annotations, doctrine, zend-framework2

I spent hours banging my head against the wall with this. The labels for my form fields didn't appear no matter what.

Finally found that without the extra space where the cursor is (see image), all annotations get ignored. I'm using ZF 2.1.1 with Doctrine Common 2.2.3.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in ZF or the Doctrine parser?

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Works:

```
   class LoginForm
   {
   /** @Annotation\Type("text")
    * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Store ID:"})
    * @Annotation\Required(true)
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
    * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength","options":{"min":2,"max":64}})
    */
   public $sStoreId;
   }
```

Fails, unless there is a space after /**:

```
   class LoginForm
   {
   /**
    * @Annotation\Type("text")
    * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Store ID:"})
    * @Annotation\Required(true)
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
    * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength","options":{"min":2,"max":64}})
    */
   public $sStoreId;
   }
```

Comment: I am having all of my @Annotations ignored as well. I threw in a @Annotation\ErrorCheckThisIsPoorlyMade() an no errors were thrown. What gives?

Comment: Also, I did find that I had to add use Zend\Form\Annotation;
To the top of the class. It uses the shortcut "Annotation" in the annotations and you need to define the namespace for that class.

Comment: Yes, `use Zend\Form\Annotation;` is needed.

Comment: Adding Zend\Form\Annotation solved my problem thanks @cr125rider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no solution so use one of the workarounds provided in the original question:

- add a space after /** (easy to forget)
- put the first annotation or any text comment in the same line as /**

Answer (score 1):

Because the annotation are using the php-doc standard, the first line is always for a comment/description. It must be given. If you provide no comment/description, leave the line empty.

Comment: Empty lines don't work. I either need to put the first annotation directly in the line of /** or put some text there (ugly) or use a space

Comment: Posted to original question.

Comment: This is common problem with ZF, whenever new release come out, most of time it breaks with doctrine. I would not be surprise if there is bug in ZF2.1.1. As for as doctrine annotation concern see examples here. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html it should work with both ways.